Is there a way to specify a compiler flag for specific target-triple in Cargo.toml?
I'd like to pass a compiler flag for a specific target. For example, there are target-feature flags that are specific to a processor like target-feature="+popcnt". I want to pass this flag only for x86_64 based targets as this does not make sense for other targets.
EDIT:
When i add
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
target-feature = "+popcnt"

Cargo gives an error
error: failed to parse manifest at Cargo.toml

Caused by:
  this virtual manifest specifies a `target` section, which is not allowed


The [target.*] sections are supposed to go into .cargo/config.toml, not Cargo.toml.
